# Transforming positional arguments of a shell script

Tags: shell, parameter

I'm trying to write a shell script that will transform positional
arguments that are passed to it as follows.

The shell script passes these arguments to a binary executable
(`ffigen`) which is derived from the `gcc 4.0` frontend, so the command
line arguments that follow are also `gcc` arguments, and mean the same
thing as they do for `gcc`.

Consider the following command line

```
./htest.sh -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I /usr/include/glib-2.0 -include \
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h -include/usr/include/bar.h /usr/include/myheader.h
```

There are essentially two different options here, the `-I` option, which
passes a directory to `gcc` to search for include files, and `-include`,
which processes a header file as if `#include "file"` appeared as the
first line of the primary source file.

The two different versions given here differ in whether there is a
space between the option flag and the argument. It seems both are
permissible.

Currently the only versions that appear in upstream are

```
-I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 and -include /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h
```

but it doesn't seem a bad idea to attempt to future-proof this code,
in case someone adds these other forms later.

What upstream's script does is, for the most part, add the arguments
to `CFLAGS`, and then pass the final argument to `ffigen`. What `ffigen` does
is not important here - my question is about the return value of
`CFLAGS`. Here is upstream's script.

```
while [ $# -gt 1 ]
do
    echo $CFLAGS
    case ${1} in
      -pthread*)
        CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -D_REENTRANT"
        shift
        ;;
      -x)
        shift
        shift
        ;;
      *)
        CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} ${1}"
        shift
        ;;
   esac
done

echo $CFLAGS
```

What I want to do, is where header filenames are specified in the
above line, is to transform them to relative path names, relative to
the include directory. So, what I would like to see as the returned
value to `CFLAGS`, is

```
-I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I /usr/include/glib-2.0 -include gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h -includebar.h
```

What upstream produces is just the arguments unchanged.

```
-I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I /usr/include/glib-2.0 -include \
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h -include/usr/include/bar.h
```

Rationale: Since Debian has switched to multilib, header files are no
longer in their traditional locations. Now, `ffigen`, like
its parent `gcc`, can search include paths for header files, *provided*
that only the relative paths are specified. If absolute paths are
specified, then of course it will not.

Ideally one would want to use a tool which was designed to work with
multiarch, but a quick and dirty workaround is to simply strip the
header file absolulute paths down to relative path names, and provided
ffigen is provided the correct include paths, it will search for and
discover the header files.

The version I currently have is below. It produces

```
-I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I glib-2.0 -include gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h bar.h
```

which is terrible, but does handle correctly the two cases that
actually occur in upstream. A version that handles all four cases
correctly would be most welcome. Yes, I'm lazy. I also suck at shell
scripting.

```
while [ $# -gt 1 ]
do
    echo $CFLAGS
    case ${1} in
      -pthread*)
        CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -D_REENTRANT"
        shift
        ;;
      -x)
        shift
        shift
        ;;
      -I*)
        CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} ${1}"
        shift
        ;;
      *)
        RELPATH_AFTER_INCLUDE="${1##*include/}"
        CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} ${RELPATH_AFTER_INCLUDE}"
        shift
        ;;
   esac
done

echo $CFLAGS
```

Here is a little script that I am using to test this

```
#!/bin/sh

PROGRAM=htest.sh
#PROGRAM=upstream.sh

./${PROGRAM} -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I /usr/include/glib-2.0 -include \     
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h -include/usr/include/bar.h /usr/include/myheader.h
```

A final note about portability. The scripts above run under dash, and
look like they are portable to me. So a version that is portable would
be nice, but is not essential. I don't see this code going upstream,
so... If not portable, then bash would be Ok.

```
###################################################################
```

For anyone who is interested in the background of this, this is in the
context of packaging [Clozure Common Lisp](http://ccl.clozure.com) for Debian.

See [the
Debian packaging](https://bitbucket.org/faheem/ccl-debian) and in particular
[the README.source file](https://bitbucket.org/faheem/ccl-debian/src/tip/README.source).

See upstream patches
http://svn.clozure.com/publicsvn/ffigen4/trunk/ffigen4/source/h-to-ffi-common
and
http://svn.clozure.com/publicsvn/ffigen4/trunk/ffigen4/source/linuxx8664-gcc-4.0.0-h-to-ffi.sh
, which combine to make the upstream script `h-to-ffi.sh`, of which I
discuss a part here.

For the specific issue I'm trying to handle here, see the thread
[problems building interface databases on Debian    multiarch](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.lisp.openmcl.devel/8037).

A discussion of my rationale above is in the third message in that
thread, from me, towards the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works, but it is kind of verbose. Suggested improvements welcome.

```
while [ $# -gt 1 ]
do
    echo $CFLAGS
    case ${1} in
      -pthread*)
        CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -D_REENTRANT"
        shift
        ;;
      -x)
        shift
        shift
        ;;
      -I)
        CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} ${1}"
        shift
        CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} ${1}"
        shift
        ;;
      -include)
        CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} ${1}"
        shift
        RELPATH_AFTER_INCLUDE="${1##*include/}"
        CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} ${RELPATH_AFTER_INCLUDE}"
        shift
        ;;
      -I*)
        CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} ${1}"
        shift
        ;;
      -include*)
        # strip off leading -include                                                                                                                              
        REMOVE_LEADING_INCLUDE="${1##-include}"
        echo "REMOVE-LEADING-INCLUDE" ${REMOVE_LEADING_INCLUDE}
        RELPATH_AFTER_INCLUDE="${REMOVE_LEADING_INCLUDE##*include/}"
        CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -include${RELPATH_AFTER_INCLUDE}"
        shift
        ;;
      *)
       CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} ${1}"
        shift
        ;;
   esac
done

echo $CFLAGS
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you sometimes have a space after `-I` or `-include` and sometimes not, you can't count on `$1` holding the option *and* the value.

I'd stick with the original version, with case choices "-pthread*", "-x" and "*". Then, after you have accumulated the CFLAGS variable, call out to sed to remove part of the path for -include option only:

```
CFLAGS=$(echo "$CFLAGS" | sed 's#\(-include \?\)/usr/include/#\1#g')
```